# Structures of The longer, The more

Tags: grammar, sentence-structure

What are the grammatical structures of the "The longer I live" and "The more I realize" in the following sentence?

> **The longer** I live, **the more** I realize the impact of attitude **on life**.

Also, why is it "on life"? Why not "in life"?

Answer (score 1):

"In life" can be used to describe the context of a statement (e.g. you won't get far in life...), but "on life" specifies that life is affected by attitude. Attitude has an impact, and life is the thing being impacted.